# Ad in integration in iOS application

Tags: iphone, admob, iad, revenue

I have one iOS universal application with more that 2 lacs users on iTunes. Currently application is free on iTunes. Now, I am thinking to add Ad integration in my application. I have some confusion for which platform I forward. Do I need to integrate iAD OR AdMob OR any other platform ? Is there any chart available which shows how much money I can earn with 2 lacs users ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best comparison : http://ecpm.adtapsy.com/mobile-ad-networks-ecpm-rates/